# android sync/download framework

Tags: android, frameworks, synchronization, download

I have to build an app that's supposed to ...

- sync a lot of XML files with a SQLite database
- sync/download even more PDF files

The lazy guy that I am, I looked for frameworks that provide some of these functionalities, so I could reduce the amount of code I'd have to produce for the before mentioned tasks, like batch downloads in separate threads.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything helpful. Which leads me to my question ...

Does anybody know a framework/library of some sort that I should have to look out for?

I did take a look into http://www.openintents.org/en/libraries already, which was a waste of time :/

Comment: r u looking for database data synchronization or files??

Comment: Actually I'm looking for both ...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to invite you to take a look at the open source project, OpenMobster's Sync service. You can do all types of sync operations (two-way,one-way client,one-way device, bootup, etc). Besides that, all modifications are automatically tracked and synced with the Cloud. You can have your app offline when network connection is down. It will track any changes and automatically in the background synchronize it with the cloud when the connection returns.

On the Cloud side you just expose your data through a Java Channel. This would be where your xml files and PDF files are injected into the Sync Channel. Once inside the Channel the data is then made available on the device for use. Any changes on either side (cloud or device) is automatically kept in sync via the Sync Channel.

The platform works on Android and iOS

Here is a link to the open source project: http://openmobster.googlecode.com

Answer (score -2):

i suggest you can look out the framework files ,maybe the files set wrong.